# Use #define from macro

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have `#define`d a preprocessor constant called `CurrentClass`.
The macro `Method` reads this constant to build a method declaration for the current class.

```
#define CurrentClass Foo
#define Method(x) \
    CurrentClass ## _ ## x

void Method(bar)() {

}
```

The preprocessor produces the following result:

```
void CurrentClass_bar() {

}
```

Obviously, `CurrentClass_bar` here should be `Foo_bar`.
The following on the other hand produces the correct result.

```
#define Method(class, x) \
    class ## _ ## x

void Method(Foo, bar)() {

}
```

For some reason, `Method` can't concatenate the constant `CurrentClass` with something else. `CurrentClass` alone produces the desired `Foo` string.

Any idea what is happening here?

Comment: That's just the way the preprocessor works. Try `#define Method(x) _Method(CurrentClass, x) / #define _Method(a, b) a ## _ ## b`.

Comment: @Kevin Nope, same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to expand it twice

```
#define xx(x0,x1) x0 ## _ ## x1
#define x(x0,x1) xx(x0,x1)
#define Method(y) \
    x(CurrentClass,y)
```

Comment: Awesome! Do you know why this is necessary?

Comment: @NSAddict I probably should make this an answer. There is an exception to when macro arguments get expanded. See this [link](http://web.mit.edu/rhel-doc/3/rhel-cpp-en-3/macro-pitfalls.html) . Scroll to `3.9.6. Argument Prescan`. It says `Macro arguments are completely macro-expanded before they are substituted into a macro body, unless they are stringified or pasted with other tokens` . In your example you use ## concatenate so the pre-scan of the arguments doesn't cause expansion. By splitting it up into 2 macros the first expands the argument and the second concatenates.

Comment: @NSAddict : To observe that the concatenations prevents the argument pre-scan take your original example `CurrentClass ## _ ## x` and replace with `CurrentClass x` . Although this experiment isn't what you want to do, review the c preprocesor output and you should notice that you get `Foo bar()` . It expanded because I removed the ## (concatenation).